# Why isn't insertBefore moving the selected object?

Tags: jquery, html

This is the structure:

[image]

I wanted to move `.am-popup` right before `#footer` so I did this:

```
$('.am-popup').insertBefore("#footer")
```

Nothing happened. I also did this:

```
$('.am-popup').insertBefore( $( "#footer" ) )
```

But nothing happened, either.

What am I doing wrong?

Live site: http://clo2015.chineselearnonline.com/amember/signup

Comment: Is that element appended dynamically?

Comment: looks like the `.am-popup` is created dynamically when you click in the `login` link... you need to executed your script after the `am-popup` is created

Comment: @Mr. Alien I'm not very sure, but I think it's not.

Comment: @Arun P Johny How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `/amember/application/default/views/public/js/user.js`, file there is a `ajaxLink(selector)` method.

In that add your script after the `amPopup(options)` line

```
//if an existing pop is present remove it
$('.am-popup .am-popup-close').trigger('click.popup');
jQuery("#ajax-link").html(html).amPopup(options);
//after creation move it
$('.am-popup').insertBefore("#footer")
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. No idea how you found the file and the method, ha.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure both `$('.am-popup')` and `$('#footer')` exist before manipulating them.

The second thing to do is make sure the `insertBefore` method is called when [DOM is ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) using:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // DOM manipulation here
});
```